# Unable to unpublish some content?

Tags: publishing, 2009

I am working in Tridion 2009, trying to remove some components. The components have been already published, so I need to unpublish first.

This component is a "Linked Schema" for several component templates and is not being used in other components anymore.

When I unpublish the component successfully, I expect that I can remove the component.

But I can't... If I check "Where is used" the tab "Published to" shows it still rendered with one or two component presentation.

Why can't I unpublish this component?

Answer (score 8):

There's a few possible reasons... but don't despair!

The Where Used information will also tell you which Publication Target the item is published to, can you make sure it's unpublished from those targets?

If you can't unpublish from those targets anymore (which can happen through configuration changes), consider using the 2009 Powertool to "Set component to unpublished" (not sure of the Powertool name anymore), or get your administrator to re-connect the publication target with your publication(s) so that you can unpublish the item.