# Component will not unpublish

Tags: 2011, publishing

I am trying to unpublish a component so I can delete it. The publishing queue states it unpublishes successfully but it still reports as published. I do a "Where Used" on the component and in the "Published To" tab it is still published to one of my publication targets.

I guess my problem is similar to "[Unable to unpublish some content?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/unable-to-unpublish-some-content)" but I'm using Tridion 2011.

Is there a 2011 way to force my component to be unpublished?

(I have several hundred of these components to delete)

Comment: I guess you have tried the obvious approach, namely to unpublish from that one publication target to which it is still published?

Comment: @Quirijn Yes I have. It reports that the unpublish action is successful.

Comment: @Quirijn I did move the component from its original location if that makes a difference? The action seems too fast. It's like when you mark the structure group as not "Publishable" and then try to (un)publish a page within that structure group - it reports success but nothing happens.

Comment: When you are unpublishing from the Publication Target it is published to, click "Show items to unpublish" and ensure that your page is there. If it is there then once the unpublish completes, from the queue open the transaction and  check the "Processed Items" tab contains your page. You have to also check "Show Successful".

Comment: @Likhan Checking the "Show items to unpublish", nothing is there. I guess this is the problem.

Comment: The component template that the published component is associated with is also published. I can't unpublish that either, same problem.

Comment: Ensure that the component template has the schema of the component in the "Linked Schema" and it is a dynamic component template. And the component was published using this component template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are unpublishing from the Publication Target it is published to, click "Show items to unpublish" and ensure that your page is there. If it is there then once the unpublish completes, from the queue open the transaction and check the "Processed Items" tab contains your page. You have to also check "Show Successful"

If you do not see the item in the list ensure that the component template has the schema of the component in the "Linked Schema" and it is a dynamic component template. And the component was published using this component template.

Comment: My issue was due to the component template not having the schema of my component in it's "Linked Schema". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no more powertools available the only solution is to manually set them as unpublished in the database.

In the CMS database you will have to look into the tables ITEM_STATES and PUBLISH_STATES and set the STATE to 0 for the specific TCMURI.

**Warning: Please do it your own risk at this may result in unpublishing the component from from multiple publications or with wrong condition you may end up with an entire "unpublished" CMS**

Comment: Thanks. I presumed this might be the answer. Doing this without confirmation from SDL Support will likely void my warranty so I'll contact them first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We are (still) using Tridion 53.

It is allowed to remove a Publication from the 'Allowed Publications List' in Publication Target even if the Publication contains the content published to that Publication Target.

If the Publication was allowed to publish to two Publication targets [Consider A & B) earlier and later restricted to one Publication target 'A' , items published to target 'B' will remain published even if you unpublish the items successfully. This is because items are unpublished only from target 'A'.

Comment: This is not the case for me but I was using 5.3 up until March 2013 so the problem likely occurred in this version.